# How to create false numerical answers in a multiple choice test dynamically?

Tags: math, multiple-choice

I am creating a small piece of software to help with mental arithmetic.

In a first level there will be numerical questions, something like "what is roughly 6 / 9.5?" and the user should get multiple choice to answer. The questions itself are dynamic. The correct answer obviously is trivial to receive (63%, or even round it to 65%), but how can I create false multiple choice answers dynamically that aren't totally easy to dismiss, but also not too close to the correct answer.

A specific example of a result I want:
Q: what is roughly 6 / 9.5?

A1: 50%
A2: 75%
A3: 65%

What I don't want is something like this:

A1: 5%
A2: 10%
A3: 65%

So I guess I want a range (which I probably have to define somehow domain wise) of possible answers depending on the level, because later on answers like A1: 60%, A2: 63%, A3: 67% might be a good challenge.

Is there any sort of "algorithm" so get to useful false answers?

Comment: One possibility would be to make a list of "typical mistakes", such as "putting the decimal point in the wrong place", "replacing addition with multiplication (or vice versa)", "forgetting the carry", etc.; then you can generate the extra choices automatically by making your program do these mistakes automatically

Comment: Another possibility is to have a list of "percentages corresponding to simple denominators", for instance 50%, 75% and 67% all correspond to fractions with very low denominators (1/2, 3/4, 2/3) whereas 43% for instance needs a relatively high denominator (3/7), and so your algorithm would pick fractions that are close to the true result but with a low denominator